# jQuery fading between classes

Tags: jquery

I am looping through three classes that display different banner background images.

I have the loop working great but want to add a fade animation between the different classes.

Here is my current code

```
    var img = ['img1', 'img2', 'img3'],
    c = 0,
    run = setInterval(loop, 3000); 

    function loop(){ 
      $('#header').removeClass().addClass(img[++c%img.length]).fadeIn('slow'); 
    }
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: It's very unclear what you're asking.

Comment: Are the classes defined in the css? Or do you dynamically want to change the `src` to an `img` element?

Comment: The classes are defined in the CSS, in each class is a different background image

Answer (score 0):

jQuery UI can handle [animations between classes](http://jqueryui.com/addClass/). Look at their documentation for [addClass](http://jqueryui.com/addClass/) and [switchClass](http://jqueryui.com/switchClass/). Their syntax is very similar to [jQuery's animate](http://api.jquery.com/animate/).

In all honesty, if you are simply looking for basic transitions, I would look into [CSS3 transitions](http://www.w3schools.com/css3/css3_transitions.asp) (please excuse the poor choice for a resource).